# how to iterate through 2d array and add elements

Tags: python, arrays

I have the following 2d array:

```
['AA' 'Call' 1]
['AAL' 'Call' 1]
['AAL' 'Put' 1]
['AAP' 'call' 1]
['AAPL' 'Call' 13]
['AAPL' 'Put' 11]
['AAWW' 'Call' 1]
['ABBV' 'put' 1]
['ABNB' 'Call' 2]
['ABNB' 'Put' 2]
['ABT' 'Call' 2]
['ACB' 'Call' 5]
['ACB' 'Put' 15]
```

here is what I want it to look like

```
['AA' 'Call' 1]
['AA' 'put' 0]
['AAL' 'Call' 1]
['AAL' 'Put' 1]
['AAP' 'call' 1]
['AAP' 'put' 0]
['AAPL' 'Call' 13]
['AAPL' 'Put' 11]
['AAWW' 'Call' 1]
['AAWW' 'Put' 0]
['ABBV' 'Call' 0]
['ABBV' 'put' 1]
['ABNB' 'Call' 2]
['ABNB' 'Put' 2]
['ABT' 'Call' 2]
['ABT' 'put' 0]
['ACB' 'Call' 5]
['ACB' 'Put' 15]
```

If the call or put is missing I want to add whichever is missing with a value of zero.
Here is my attempt:

```py
i =  0
while i < len(arr):
    if(i+1<len(arr) and i>0):
        if((arr[i][0]!=arr[i+1][0]) and (arr[i-1][0]!=arr[i][0])):
            if(arr[i][1]=='Call'):
                ticker = arr[i][0]
                val = [ticker,'Put','0']
                arr = np.insert(arr, i+1,val)
                i += 1
            elif(arr[i][1]=='Put'):
                ticker = arr[i][0]
                val = [ticker,'Call','0']
                arr = np.insert(arr, i-1,val)
                i +=1
    i += 1
```

The order has to be Call first followed by puts. What am I missing here?

Comment: What is the problem with the code? What does it do differently than you want?

Comment: @mkrieger1 it has an error saying string index out of range

Comment: Do you understand what that means?

Comment: it means that I am trying to access an index that does not exists however the reason I have I > 0 on the third line is to make sure that doesnt happen.

Comment: the error on this statement  if(arr[i][1]=='Call'): (4th line ) right after going through AAL

Comment: your data has instances of `Put` and lower case `put`? similarly, `Call` vs `call` or is that a issue while you have added that example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's a solution:

```
arr=[
['AA','Call', 1],
['AAL', 'Call', 1],
['AAL', 'Put', 1],
['AAP', 'Call', 1],
['AAPL', 'Call', 13],
['AAPL', 'Put', 11],
['AAWW', 'Call', 1],
['ABBV', 'Put', 1],
['ABNB', 'Call', 2],
['ABNB', 'Put', 2],
['ABT', 'Call', 2],
['ACB', 'Call', 5],
['ACB', 'Put', 15]]

i=0
while i < len(arr):
    if i+1<len(arr):
        if arr[i][0]!=arr[i+1][0]:
            if arr[i][1]=='Call':
                arr.insert(i+1,[arr[i][0],'Put',0])
            else:
                arr.insert(i,[arr[i][0],'Call',0])            
        i += 1            
    else:
        if arr[i][1]=='Call':
            arr.append([arr[i][0],'Put',0])
        else:
            arr.insert(i,[arr[i][0],'Call',0])
        i += 1
        
    i += 1
```

Note that you need to cater for the last item in the list (i.e. when `i+1` is out of bounds).

Comment: I am getting this error ````AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'insert'````

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is with `np.insert`. By default it first flattens the array, than inserts new data, so after the first insert our array becomes 1D, and the second index starts to apply to the string element returned by the first indexing. That's why the error. You should have understood it earlier if you used `arr[i, 0]` instead of `arr[i][0]`.
To avoid flattening, you need to specify an axis along which to insert the new values. In your case it is axis 0, so you need to have

```
arr = np.insert(arr, i+1,val, axis=0)
...
arr = np.insert(arr, i-1,val, axis=0)
```

Even after that the result is different from the example you posted, and the reason is in conditions you use. I don't know which one is wrong: the example or the conditions,  but believe you will be able to fix it yourself.